# Upload videos to twitter from url in node

Tags: node.js, api, twitter, stream, fs

In my app I want to post a video to multiple networks (fb, twitter...), i'm uploading video to cloudinary and it sends back url, which I use to post to fb.

For twitter, there is no way to post a video with the url. Is there any alternatives to do this?

My server size is pretty low, like 1-2GB, so I can't download a video to my server and then create a stream to upload to twitter. I worry that if 3-4 users started to upload then my server will crash with out of memory.

Any suggestions using `twit` package or Simple HTTP Requests are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I had found an interesting article on how to upload your files to third party. [Streaming File Uploads to Storage Server with Node.js](http://qnimate.com/stream-file-uploads-to-storage-server-in-node-js/)

So you can update the code from the example with your twitter upload code.

Comment: looks like this is just to stream images from the other servers, instead of prod server. I couldn't figure out, how it will solve my issue.